# vb.net display database record to a different combobox from a single database table with different records

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

vb.net display database record to a different combobox from a single database table with different records

i have two comboboxes and i want to show different records in each combobox, and i'm only using one table in my database, this code shows error, hmm

my table schema:

`| cid | cpos........| cfname | cmname | clname | cyr | cparty |
 |  1..| president. | john....| ark....|..smith.| 3 ..| glory..|`

```
Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.ConnectionString = ("server=localhost;user id=root;database=db")
    Try
        con.Open()

        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = "SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', cfname, cmname, clname,'from', cparty WHERE cpos like='President') AS fullname from candidate;"
        End With
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        With ComboBox1
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(dt)
            .DataSource = dt
            .DisplayMember = "fullname"
            .ValueMember = "fullname"
        End With


        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = "SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', cfname, cmname, clname,'from', cparty WHERE cpos like='Vice President') AS fullname from candidate;"
        End With
        With ComboBox2
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(dt)
            .DataSource = dt
            .DisplayMember = "fullname"
            .ValueMember = "fullname"
        End With


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry but that queries make no sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to show President in the first combobox and Vice President in the second, the records are in the same table in the database.

Comment: Can you add the full schema of the table candidate (name of every fields and their type)

Comment: there you go. i edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your previous question, I think that your commandtext should be something like this

```
.Connection = con
.CommandText = "SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', cfname, cmname, clname, cparty) as fullname " & _
               "from candidate WHERE cpos like='Vice President'"
```

This will join the info from the four columns `cfname, cmname, clname and cparty` in a single column named fullname, then a where condition on the field cpos will extract the 'Vice President' or 'President' roles.

Also I suggest to change the order of the properties setting on the combobox

```
 .DisplayMember = "fullname"
 .ValueMember = "fullname"
 .DataSource = dt
```

You could also avoid to execute two queries to retrieve the same info from your database in this way

```
 With cmd
    .Connection = con

    ' If you have only President and Vice President in the candidate table 
    ' you could remove the where clause 
    .CommandText = "SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', cfname, cmname, clname, cparty) as fullname, " & _
                   "cpos, cid from candidate WHERE cpos like='Vice President' OR " & _
                   "cpos like 'President'"
 End With
```

then you separate your data using a DataView as DataSource of your Combobox

```
da.SelectCommand = cmd
da.Fill(dt)
With ComboBox1
   Dim dv = new DataView(dt, "cpos like 'President'", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
   .DisplayMember = "fullname"
   .ValueMember = "fullname"
   .DataSource = dv
End With
With ComboBox2
   Dim dv1 = new DataView(dt, "cpos like 'Vice President'", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
   .DisplayMember = "fullname"
   .ValueMember = "fullname"
   .DataSource = dv1
End With
```

Comment: it's not working? it's not showing vice president in combobox2

Comment: it has error in `"cpos like 'Vice President', "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)` and in `.DataSource = dv1` it says String constants must end with a double quote

Comment: Please refresh the page, Probably I was still fixing small typos  when you used this code.....

Comment: cannot find column cpos?

Comment: Uhm, right we need to add it to the query, updating the answer again

Comment: Added the column cpos and cid to the list of fields returned by the query. If `cid` is a primary key it could be useful to use it as ValueMember of your combobox instead of `fullname` because it will be easier to query again the database with that field value instead of the inexistant field `fullname`